# How to update a field in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need update a field with the same table. In the example below The RewRate is set correct in Co 1 , then I need updated the NewRate for Co 4, 10 and 16. based on the EDL Type, EDL Code. Thanks

[image]

This code is obviously wrong, but i just do not know how to fix it. sorry

```
  UPDATE       PRCI
   SET   NewRate = (select NewRate from PRCI  where PRCI.PRCo=1 and Craft ='xxx')
```

Sorry for the confusing. I need update 
EDL Code300 NewRate 0.05, 
EDL Code700 NewRate 5.3
EDL Code701 NewRate 3.7
EDL Code707 NewRate 0.78
EDL Code714 NewRate 3

For company 4 10 and 16

Comment: This is wrong because inner query can return more than one rows. Try using MAX(NewRate) and also put where clause after setting. Otherwise you're gonna update everything.

Comment: That would make it 5.3.  He wants 3.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing. I need update EDL Code300 NewRate 0.05, EDL Code700 NewRate 5.3 EDL Code701 NewRate 3.7 EDL Code707 NewRate 0.78 EDL Code714 NewRate 3

Comment: Which field you need to update ? what should be the value of that field ? Please clarify this.

Comment: So, you want to update NewRate for all rows where PRCo <> 1 so that they match the values for NewRate where PRCo=1? You're nearly there with your statement- add some table aliases to avoid confusion and join on the identifying columns (EDL Type etc)

Comment: Unless you can have multiple rows for the identifying columns, in which case you'll need an aggregate function and group by in your subquery

Comment: Actually you don't need a sub query.  Ashish's answer looks about right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.NewRate=t2.NewRate
FROM PRCI t1 
INNER JOIN PRCI t2
ON t1.EDLType=t2.EDLType
AND t1.EDLCode=t2.EDLCode
WHERE t1.PRCo!='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
and Craft ='xxx'
```

to

```
and EDLCode = 714.
```

As mentioned in the comments, a where clause might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal? It is not clear... Please describe the task more detailed.

Your sql is wrong, because the sub select returns multiple results, but only single result is expected... You may create a stored procedure or anonym block with a cursor. Make that cursor for select the distincted PRCo,Craft,EDL Type, EDL Code. Then fetch the key values and update the NewRate for each fetched keys with the calculated value.4